# Python aggregate time series using a complex function that depends on the value from anther column

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

My time series is something like this:

```
TranID,Time,Price,Volume,SaleOrderVolume,BuyOrderVolume,Type,SaleOrderID,SaleOrderPrice,BuyOrderID,BuyOrderPrice
1,09:25:00,137.69,200,200,453,B,182023,137.69,241939,137.69
2,09:25:00,137.69,253,300,453,S,184857,137.69,241939,137.69
3,09:25:00,137.69,47,300,200,B,184857,137.69,241322,137.69
4,09:25:00,137.69,153,200,200,B,219208,137.69,241322,137.69
```

I can do the aggregation by suming all the Volume

`res = df.resample('t').agg({'Volume': 'sum'})`

But I would like to aggregate the volume and type columns according to **volume** and **type** column in the way that when type is **S** then add the volume otherwise remove the volume. If the total volume after aggregation is negative then type is **S** otherwise type is **B**.

In the above example, after I aggregate the volume, the total volume would become

`200 - 253 + 300 + 200 = 447`

and the type is **B** since 447 > 0

result:

```
Time,Volume,Type
09:25:00,447,B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to multiply the volume by 1 or -1 depending on the value in Type with `map`. then `assign` the column Type depending on the result of the summed volume.

```
res = (
    (df['Volume']*df['Type'].map({'S':-1, 'B':1}))
      .groupby(df['Time']).sum()#here should work with resample, 
                                #just your input is not the right format to use resample
      .reset_index(name='Volume')
      .assign(Type=lambda x: np.where(x['Volume']>0, 'B', 'S'))
)

print(res)
       Time  Volume Type
0  09:25:00     147    B # you used 2 columns to calculate your result volume 447?
```